# How to add Date in MySQL with Codeigniter db->insert() method

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am saving date of birth in MySQLusing my form with

```
db->insert()
```

method, but it's not properly inserted in the database. How can I save the input field value  in the proper date format in MySQL? (In MySQL the type of dob is also set to "DATE".)

Comment: Kindly provide the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

*MYSQL DATE* - A date in **`YYYY-MM-DD format`**

so you need to convert via sql or php

***PHP***

<strike>$date= date('YYYY-MM-DD',strtotime($old_date));</strike>

```
$date= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($old_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have taken your dateofbirth field's datatype as `date` then you have to insert date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.